# Can I export animations from MotionLayout?

Tags: android, video, export, mp4, android-motionlayout

What is the best way to export an animation created with motionlayout?
Create a video recording the screen? Gif? What do you think?

An example is something like the app "mojo" in google play, Link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=video.mojo

They created a mp4 video with animated layouts